# Merging multiple dataframess in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind, cbind

I have an issue with multiple dataframes needing merging. I tried rbind, cbind and the basic merge. But it doesn't give me satisfactory results. My problem is below:

First df:

```
Common, Col 2, Col 3
A, 2, 3
B, 3, 4
C, 4, 5
D, 5, 6
```

Second df:

```
Common, Col 3, Col 4
B, 4, 5
D, 6, 6
E, 3, 4
```

Third df:

```
Common, Col 1, Col 2
A, a, 2
C, f, 4
F, g, 1
```

When I combine it, I want:

```
Common, Col 1, Col 2, Col 3, Col 4
A, a, 2, NA, NA
B, NA, 3, 4, 5
C, f, 4, 5, NA
D, NA, 5, 6, 6
E, NA, NA, 3, 4
F, g, 1, NA, NA
```

My current code for combining multiple df's together uses:

```
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern="*df"))
New_df <- do.call(rbind.fill, df_list)
```

The rbind.fill method does not work well. It basically does not collapse the rows as required.

I tried the multmerge() from the link below. But can't get it to work. 
https://www.r-bloggers.com/merging-multiple-data-files-into-one-data-frame/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to match columns, it is a join operation, `rbind` won't do it, you need `merge`; And `merge` by default set `by = intersect(names(x), names(y))`, i.e. common columns, so you can just use `Reduce()` function to merge the data frames one by one assuming they have already been collected into a list:

```
Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all=T), df_list)

#  Common Col.2 Col.3 Col.4 Col.1
#1      A     2     3  <NA>     a
#2      B     3     4     5  <NA>
#3      C     4     5  <NA>     f
#4      D     5     6     6  <NA>
#5      E  <NA>     3     4  <NA>
#6      F     1  <NA>  <NA>     g
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixes the issue.

Comment: Hello, I think the above solution does not work as I wanted it to. It basically introduces duplicates in Column Common (A,A,B,B,C,C,D,D,E,F). Can I make it give me (A,B,C,D,E,F). So left most column needs to be unique.

Comment: `merge` creates duplicated keys when you have duplicated keys in your original data. You may want to check on that firstly.

Comment: You are right @Psidom , now I have different datasets that have identical first column, but the other columns may or may not be identical. How do I combine these to create a master dataset, that is unique by column one but includes everything else too. For any given index in column one, other columns present in different datasets are identical with additional columns that need to be added in.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are after. If you want to keep the first column unique, either use `unique()` on all data frames to see if there are still duplicated values, or if it doesn't work then it means you have to apply some aggregate method on your data set grouped by the key column.

Comment: I unfortunately have duplicates alon with additional (non-duplicate column) and have to club everything together (some form of overwrite is needed for duplicate columns. What do you think about this approach:
Trimmed_DF <- aggregate(Combined_DF[-1], by=list(Combined_DF$Column1), SomeFunc)

Combined_DF is a combined DF with duplicated Column 1 values. I want to collapse (not exclude) those rows. 

Also, SomeFunc is an issue, i don't think i need a func there, think I need something else there.

Answer (score 0):

An inelegant solution is:

```
A = data.frame(c1 = c(1, 2), c3 = c('yes', 'no'))
B = data.frame(c2 = c(1, 2), c4 = c('Tokyo', 'Berlin'))

A1 = cbind(A, c2 = rep(NA, 2), c4 = rep(NA, 2))
B1 = cbind(B, c1 = rep(NA, 2), c3 = rep(NA, 2))

rbind(A1, B1)
```

Which produces

```
  c1   c3 c2     c4
1  1  yes NA   <NA>
2  2   no NA   <NA>
3 NA <NA>  1  Tokyo
4 NA <NA>  2 Berlin
```